# GHC: Haskell string optimizations

Tags: list, haskell, ghc

I know [`Data.Text`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-0.11.2.2) is a much more efficient way of storing string data than `String = [Char]`. However, it seems that a number of functions I see in libraries expect a `String` passed to them. A linked list of `Char`s seems very inefficient to read, considering pointers will take up more space than the string itself. Besides list fusion (which may not always be possible), are there any optimizations that GHC makes to the storage of `[Char]`'s, and does it apply similar principles to other lists?

Comment: I doubt there are too many string-specific optimizations--it seems anything you could do to improve a list of Chars could also be done to a list of Ints or whatever else you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason why all the base library functions use `String` instead of a more efficient type is that the *text* library needed for `Text` is not part of the base library.  However, the text library provides its own variants of the various input/output functions.  You can find them in `Data.Text.IO`.

Also note that for efficient I/O you would normally use one of the modern abstractions likes conduits, iteratees or pipes.

Answer (score 2):

Under GHC, `String` uses [5 words per code point](http://blog.johantibell.com/2011/06/memory-footprints-of-some-common-data.html) in the average case. This is, however, mitigated by the fact that the runtime preallocates characters in the ASCII range.

Answer (score -1):

[Here](http://learnyouahaskell.com/input-and-output#bytestrings) is the answer.

> **Bytestring**'s are sort of like lists, only each element is one byte (or 8 bits) in size. The way they handle laziness is also different.

Comment: ByteStrings represent sequences of bytes that can represent any kind of data while String and Text are intended for Unicode text. They are two different things.